# Why is my print() output printing on two lines?

Tags: python, list, printing

I'm trying to print a list of files for air quality data. The files are listed in a .txt file called 'list.txt'

This is what the list looks like:
https://tropomi.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/data/S5P_TROPOMI_Level2/S5P_L2__NO2___.1/2018/120/S5P_RPRO_L2__NO2____20180430T153222_20180430T171550_02827_01_010202_20190201T152559.nc

This is the simple code I wrote:

```
filelist = open('list.txt')

for i in filelist:
    print(i)
```

And this is the output:
Output: https://tropomi.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/data/S5P_TROPOMI_Level2/S5P_L2__NO2___.1/2018/120/
S5P_RPRO_L2__NO2____20180430T153222_20180430T171550_02827_01_010202_20190201T152559.nc

The file name is appearing on two lines instead of one - why is this happening?

Comment: Because `print()` in python automatically prints a newline after its argument. If you want to print on one line, format a single string to contain everything you want, then print that.

Comment: BTW, using `list` as a variable name clobbers [a builtin function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list).

Comment: @FredLarson - noted, I will change it.

Answer (score -2):

```
list = open('list.txt','r')
list = list.readlines()

for i in list:
    print(i)
```

Comment: How does this help?

Comment: in your code list is a file object. and in my code, I am reading data from the file object

Comment: @harshilsuthar you can iterate over a file objects without `readlines()`.

Comment: yes, you can but it will give you a string instead of a list. new lines will be inside the string like 'data \nhello world'. by using readlines you will get a list like ['data', 'hello world']. its more preferable way.